# Include client side script in Vue JS app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, client-side-scripting

I'm new to Vue JS and i'm working on app that's already built by someone. I need to include a script that should be render in client-side and not in server side. I put the script after the body end tag like other scripts but i observed that its being rendered on server-side.

Thats script is working fine in plain HTML file.

Can anyone help me on this..

Comment: What do you mean it's being rendered on server side?

Comment: The app being build in self-hosted gitlab and it's protocol in HTTP, Our website being hosted in HTTPS. The script is identifying the protocol using window.location.protocol and it's giving HTTP not HTTPS.

Comment: Use the `static` folder.

Comment: @WaldemarIce that is on-line script not off-line. any other way..?

Comment: @ShankarAkunuri Which one? From any CDN? Just download it... If you can't, just include it in the head section of the index.html file. And don't forget the `defer` attribute.

Comment: @WaldemarIce script is not executing when using `defer`. getting function not defined exception while calling function from the script.